Tkinter back and forward buttons re: visited history
My app displays details for one person at a time based on a current_person_id and other information related to that person which is stored in a database. I wanted to change the details displayed based on the order in which different persons' details had been seen, so it would work like a browser's back/forward button.
I found instructions here, here, and here which suggested using two stacks, one for the back button and one for the forward button. I didn't understand these instructions so I compared them with each other and compiled a more succinct and better organized set of instructions.
It took several hours but I finally managed to get this to work in Tkinter. I will answer my question below.

FYI you can post both question and answer at the same time by ticking a checkbox while typing out the question.

The back stack and forward stack start out empty.
On navigate to new page not using back/forward

clear forward stack
append current page to back stack

On click back

append current page to forward stack
pop last page from the back stack
set current to popped page

On click forward

append current page to back stack
pop last page from forward stack
set current to popped page


In a class the global variables can be changed to instance variables.
import tkinter as tk
bck_stack = []
fwd_stack = []
current_person_id = 1

def change_current_person(key):
    """ Append current_person_id to forward or backward stack before changing 
        it to its new value. The current_person_id is not in either stack.    
    """
    global fwd_stack, current_person_id
    if key == "changer":
        got = ent.get()
        if len(got) == 0:
            return
        fwd_stack = []
        bck_stack.append(current_person_id)
        current_person_id = got
        redraw(current_person_id)
        ent.delete(0, "end")
    elif key == "back":
        if len(bck_stack) == 0:
            pass            
        else:
            fwd_stack.append(current_person_id)
            current_person_id = bck_stack.pop()
            redraw(current_person_id)
    elif key == "forward":
        if len(fwd_stack) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            bck_stack.append(current_person_id)
            current_person_id = fwd_stack.pop()
            redraw(current_person_id)

def redraw(current_person_id):
    current["text"] = current_person_id
    bck_history.delete("1.0", "end")
    bck_history.insert("1.0", bck_stack)
    fwd_history.delete("1.0", "end")
    fwd_history.insert("1.0", fwd_stack)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    buttons = {}

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("+700+300")
    root.config(bg="black")
    lab_bck = tk.Label(
        root, text="Back Stack", anchor="w", bg="black", fg="white")
    bck_history = tk.Text(
        root, width=40, height=4, bg="steelblue", fg="white")
    bck_history.insert("1.0", "Back history displays here.")

    lab_fwd = tk.Label(
        root, text="Forward Stack", anchor="w", bg="black", fg="white")
    fwd_history = tk.Text(
       root, width=40, height=4, bg="steelblue", fg="white")
    fwd_history.insert("1.0", "Forward history displays here.")

    ent = tk.Entry(root, bg="steelblue", fg="white")
    for key in ("changer", "back", "forward"):
        buttons[key] = tk.Button(
        root, bg="teal", command=lambda key=key: change_current_person(key))        

    current = tk.Label(
        root, width=5, height=1, bg="blue", fg="white", 
        font=("arial black", 21), text=current_person_id)

    buttons["changer"]["text"] = "CHANGE CURRENT PERSON"
    buttons["back"]["text"] = "BACK"
    buttons["forward"]["text"] = "FORWARD"

    lab_bck.grid(column=0, row=0)
    bck_history.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=3)
    lab_fwd.grid(column=0, row=2)
    fwd_history.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=3)
    ent.grid(column=0, row=4)
    buttons["changer"].grid(column=1, row=4)
    current.grid(column=2, row=4)
    buttons["back"].grid(column=0, row=5)
    buttons["forward"].grid(column=1, row=5)

    ent.focus_set()

    root.mainloop()


